# Inkscape .HTML SVG file works in Chrome but not in IE9

Tags: html, google-chrome, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have the following Inkscape exported SVG:

[TESTSVG.HTML]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448819"
   height="1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="mainscreen.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="175.99454"
     inkscape:cy="739.86976"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="706"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-width:23.16900062999999900;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="circle1"
       sodipodi:cx="227.14285"
       sodipodi:cy="156.6479"
       sodipodi:rx="47.142857"
       sodipodi:ry="44.285713"
       d="m 274.28571,156.6479 a 47.142857,44.285713 0 1 1 -94.28571,0 47.142857,44.285713 0 1 1 94.28571,0 z"
       inkscape:label="#path2985" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-width:4.86899999999999980;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="box1"
       width="284.28571"
       height="110"
       x="312.85715"
       y="98.076469"
       inkscape:label="#box1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Save as an HTML file (TESTSVG.HTML), it works in Chrome but not in IE9. If you change the file name to .SVG (TESTSVG.SVG), it will work on both browsers.

I need to make it work on IE9 using the HTML extension.

Tks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's acceptable to have two files, you can do the following (tested in IE9). You'd save your SVG as test.svg in this case:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<object data='test.svg'></object>  



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an HTML DTD like this and embed the SVG (works in IE10 - can't test in 9) *should work* I think

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448819"
   height="1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.4 r9939"
   sodipodi:docname="mainscreen.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="175.99454"
     inkscape:cy="739.86976"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1366"
     inkscape:window-height="706"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <path
       sodipodi:type="arc"
       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-

width:23.16900062999999900;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-

linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-

dasharray:none"
       id="circle1"
       sodipodi:cx="227.14285"
       sodipodi:cy="156.6479"
       sodipodi:rx="47.142857"
       sodipodi:ry="44.285713"
       d="m 274.28571,156.6479 a 47.142857,44.285713 0 1 1 -94.28571,0 

47.142857,44.285713 0 1 1 94.28571,0 z"
       inkscape:label="#path2985" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#ffff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#495677;stroke-

width:4.86899999999999980;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-

linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-

dasharray:none"
       id="box1"
       width="284.28571"
       height="110"
       x="312.85715"
       y="98.076469"
       inkscape:label="#box1" />
  </g>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same problem. Doesn´t work with IE9... Only with Chrome. No messages on IE9 console... Very strange.

Comment: Did you try my other answer?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem - IE9 refuses to render svg's from InkScape when the code is implemented inline in HTML.

The problem is the tag `<sodipodi:namedview` and everything in here until the closing tag `/>`

Try removing this and I bet the svg will render when the HTML is called in IE9.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `inkscape` and `sodipodi` are not recognized in IE9, especially for inline SVGs. That's why they need to be removed. You can refer to this link [Simple SVG Display](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Use.html)